# PHP session records return only one record

Tags: php, session, output, record

I have multiple record for the session `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` like

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => sms, "quantity" => $pe, "to" =>$to, "msg" => $message));
```

please see here https://ideone.com/NZysQc

In my achievement I was trying to output this record in a different page but it output only one record. What is mine doing wrong? This is my tried code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
    $id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $to = $each_item['to'];
    echo '$to and $id';
}
```

But it return only one record in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo '$to and $id';
```

For:

```
echo "$to and $id";
```

As vars are not parsed inside simple quoted strings.

Your example has only the element 0, so only one element will be shown.

You could [array_push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) your elements to you cart session var to have more than one element. And set it to the new array only if the var is stil not set.

```
$newItem = array("item_id" => sms, "quantity" => $pe, "to" =>$to, "msg" => $message);
if (empty($_SESSION["cart_array"]))
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => $newItem);
else
    array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], $newItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be as such:-

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"][] = array("item_id" => $sms, "quantity" => $pe, "to" => $to, "msg" => $message);
```

to form the array and

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
    $id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $to = $each_item['to'];
    echo "$to and $id";
}
```

for the loop, notice the double quotes in the `echo`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => sms, "quantity" => $pe, "to" =>$to, "msg" => $message),1 => array("item_id" => sms, "quantity" => $pe, "to" =>$to, "msg" => $message));
```

`foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item_array)
 {
      foreach ($each_item_array as $each_item)
      {
    $id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $to = $each_item['to'];
    echo "$to and $id </br>";
        }
}`

Comment: Please use block formatting for code that spans over several lines - it's the `{}` icon in the editor toolbar.